# how to search Soundcloud HTTP API for username with spaces

Tags: soundcloud

It appears that calls to the Soundcloud API with a query containing a space will fail as API search appears to only search the Permalink field, example:

http://api.soundcloud.com/users.json?q=memory%20echo&consumer_key=CONSUMERKEY&limit=20&offset=0

This is not returning the artist Memory Echo at all. If I just search for the word "memory" then I can find it after paging through 8 pages of 20 users.

How can I get results that include an artists name with a space in it as part of the larger set of search results that should be associated with the words "memory" and "echo"? Is it possible to tell the API to specifically search the Username field?

Comment: have u read the docs? where is the problem? first response is "memory echo" http://api.soundcloud.com/users.json?q=memory%20echo&client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28

Comment: I don't get Memory Echo in the response at all. first response is "Vinky Official", and that is using the link you provided. Yes, I've read the docs, keep reading the docs more than four years, have a published app with 81k users, but search is misbehaving recently.

Comment: Incredibly odd, I get the same results as @bnz with my own ```client_id```.  Have you tried creating a new app and using a fresh token?

Comment: So, it is working now. I'm going to guess this was some kind of database sync issue on Soundcloud as I haven't changed the code in my app and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question: Probably not.

You probably already know this, but if there is a way to do it, it isn't documented by SoundCloud.  As much as it may suck, you probably are going to have to continue to crunch through search results yourself to find the correct username unless you can convince the folks at SoundCloud to add that feature onto their API.

You may be able to optimize your search by guessing the user's permalink (which appears to often be the username in lowercase with spaces removed) and falling back to a full search if the search with the permalink fails to find the user you are looking for.

Using this scheme, searching for "Memory Echo" would first call `/users.json?q=memoryecho` and then fall back to `/users.json?q=Memory Echo` if the first query failed to turn up the correct user.

Also, FYI, I tried the link provided by @bnz and also got "Memory Echo" as the first response. When I searched "memoryecho", username "Memory Echo" was the only result.